# what does 안으로 샐죽하니 튀들어 가지 않느냐. mean?

Tags: vocabulary

안으로 샐죽하니 튀들어 가지 않느냐. 
so I looked up serjjuk and tidrruh so I know what they mean but what does the author mean by 안으로. I know it means "inside" but I don't get the sentence means.

딴은 내가 더 단단히 덤비지 않 고 그랬다. 나도 저쪽 벽을 향하여 외면하면서 내 말로, “안 된다는걸 그럼 어떡헌담!” 하니까, “쇰을 잡아 채지 그냥 둬, 이 바보야!” 하고또 얼굴이 빨개지면서 성을 내며 안으로 샐죽하니 튀들어 가지 않느냐.

if it's easier to explain in Korean feel free to use korean.

Comment: Why do you study a novel in old style ?

Comment: because it came with an korean/english glossary. of course the glossary isn't perfect but it's convenient

Answer (score 1):

1) 샐죽하면서 안으로 튀들어 = 안으로 샐죽하면서 튀들어 = go inside with slant

2) 샐죽하니 안으로 튀들어 = 안으로 샐죽하니 튀들어 = go inside as like cow put out tongue

[old]

> 1) 쌜쭉하다 : 어떤 감정의 표현으로서 입이나 눈을 한쪽으로 샐긋하고(slightly slant) 움직이는 모양.

Expressing his feeling through moving his eye or lip.

그가 입술을 샐쭉하고 웃으며 나에게 다가왔다.

He is coming to me with smiling after moving his lip.

> 2) 안으로 샐죽하니 튀들어 가지 않느냐

Is it true that she did not run suddenly into inside with moving her
lip ?

=> She did run suddenly into inside with moving her lip.

@ It is a part of 김유정's novel " 봄봄 " (1935). In Korea, it can
be studied in the high school Korean-novel class.

@@ 튀들어 : compare with 튀어 나오다 = pop out

Comment: I think I got confused with the word order because it's more logical  to say 안으로 샐죽하면서 튀들어 가지 않느냐 or   샐죽하니 안으로 튀들어 가지 않느냐. the way it's originally written is irritating to me lol.

Comment: [add] 샐쭉하다 = 쌜죽하다 (they share almost same meaning) : 1) moving of
lip or eye

2) exposing a feeling which is not satisfied

Comment: And 안으로 is adverb so that 안으로 샐죽하면서 or switching are fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think 샐쭉하다 is a rather old-fashioned word, but in this case the meaning is probably a combination of [these two entries](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=20546303):

> (동사) 어떤 감정을 나타내면서 입이나 눈이 한쪽으로 약간 샐그러지게 움직이다. 또는 그렇게 하다.
>
> (형용사) 마음에 차지 아니하여서 약간 고까워하는 데가 있다.

- Apparently 샐쭉하다 is the standard form, not 샐죽하다, according to Naver dictionary.

Okay, even that is hard to parse, but I think it is basically the same class of emotion as "pouting".  You're unsatisfied/angry with something so you're thrusting your lips in an ugly way.

Here, -(하)니 is (obviously) not a question, but an ending for 형용사 meaning "in this manner".  I think it's rather uncommon these days, and only appears in a handful of expressions.

> 아기가 **곤하니**/곤히/곤하게 잠이 들었다. = The baby is soundly asleep.
>
> 뭘 그렇게 **멍하니**/멍하게 쳐다보냐? = What are you looking at so absentmindedly?
>
> **가지런하니**/가지런히/가지런하게 자라는 나무들 = Trees growing in an ordered row

So, 샐죽하니 is basically the same as 샐죽한 얼굴로, or 샐죽해 하며.

I'm not sure 튀들어 is even standard Korean.  It might be a very old fashioned expression or a dialect.  In modern speech it will certainly be 튀어들어.

Finally, 가지 않느냐 is not asking "did she go", but gives an air of conversation, and shows that the narrator found it remarkable, surprising, or maybe outrageous.  More like "She really went in, didn't she?" or maybe "And she just went in!  Can you believe that?"

In modern spoken Korean, you may find a similar pattern like this:

> 그러더니 그냥 돌아서서 (**가는 거 아니겠어** / 가는 거 있지)?
>
> = Then [she] just turned back and walked away!

---

Bringing it all together, my translation would be:

> ... 안으로 샐죽하니 튀들어 가지 않느냐.
>
> ... and then she just pops inside, pouting!

Comment: thanks for all the example sentences. I feel more certain that I understood the sentence now with all these concrete examples.